# About the "GetBytes" implementation in BitConverter

Tags: c#, c++, bitconverter

I've found that the implementation of the `GetBytes` function in .net framework is something like:

```
public unsafe static byte[] GetBytes(int value)
{
   byte[] bytes = new byte[4];
   fixed(byte* b = bytes)
     *((int*)b) = value;
   return bytes;
}
```

I'm not so sure I understand the full details of these two lines:

```
   fixed(byte* b = bytes)
     *((int*)b) = value;
```

Could someone provide a more detailed explanation here? And how should I implement this function in standard C++?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Could someone provide a more detailed explanation here?

The [MSDN documentation for `fixed`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f58wzh21.aspx) comes with *numerous* examples and explanation -- if that's not sufficient, then you'll need to clarify which specific part you don't understand.

---

> And how should I implement this function in standard C++?

```cpp
#include <cstring>
#include <vector>

std::vector<unsigned char> GetBytes(int value)
{
    std::vector<unsigned char> bytes(sizeof(int));
    std::memcpy(&bytes[0], &value, sizeof(int));
    return bytes;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed tells the garbage collector not to move a managed type so that you can access that type with standard pointers.

In C++, if you're not using C++/CLI (i.e. not using .NET) then you can just use a byte-sized pointer (char) and loop through the bytes in whatever you're trying to convert.

Just be aware of endianness...

Answer (score 0):

First fixed has to be used because we want to assign a pointer to a managed variable:

> The fixed statement prevents the garbage collector from relocating a
>   movable variable. The fixed statement is only permitted in an unsafe
>   context. Fixed can also be used to create fixed size buffers.
>
> The fixed statement sets a pointer to a managed variable and "pins"
>   that variable during the execution of the statement. Without fixed,
>   pointers to movable managed variables would be of little use since
>   garbage collection could relocate the variables unpredictably. **The
>   C# compiler only lets you assign a pointer to a managed variable in a
>   fixed statement.**   [Ref](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f58wzh21%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

Then we declare a pointer to byte and assign to the start of the byte array.

Then, we cast the pointer to byte to a pointer to int, dereference it and assign it to the int passed in.

Answer (score 0):

The function creates a byte array that contains the same binary data as your platform's representation of the integer `value`. In C++, this can be achieved (for any type really) like so:

```
int value; // or any type!
unsigned char b[sizeof(int)];
unsigned char const * const p = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char const *>(&value);
std::copy(p, p + sizeof(int), b);
```

Now `b` is an array of as many bytes as the size of the type `int` (or whichever type you used).

In C# you need to say `fixed` to obtain a raw pointer, since usually you do not have raw pointers in C# on account of objects not having a fixed location in memory -- the garbage collector can move them around at any time. `fixed` prevents this and fixes the object in place so a raw pointer can make sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement GetBytes() for any POD type with a simple function template.

```
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
std::vector<unsigned char> GetBytes(T value)
{
    return std::vector<unsigned char>(reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(&value),
                                      reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(&value) + sizeof(value));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a C++ header-only library that may be of help.

[BitConverter](https://github.com/YanjieHe/BitConverter)

The idea of implementing the `GetBytes` function in C++ is straight-forward: compute each byte of the value according to specified layout. For example, let's say we need to get the bytes of an unsigned 16-bit integer in big endian. We can divide the value by 256 to get the first byte, and take the remainder as the second byte.

For floating-point numbers, the algorithm is a little bit more complicated. We need to get the sign, exponent, and mantissa of the number, and encode them as bytes. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format